# Jasvascript : Alert notification after inactivity and logging out after 5 more minutes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a little problem regarding browser window closing,

Basically, I have a page which I want to close after 15 minutes of inactivity. I alraeady managed to make a timer that will alert the window after inactivity for 10 minutes.

What I need is that on timer finish, a popup/alert with a visible countdown comes up and from here the user can either continue with his session or end it. If the user does not click on continue or ignore the popup for 5 more minutes, both the popup and parent window will close. Else if the user presses continue the popup will close and the main page is refreshed (and thus starting the timer again) Any suggestions? Here is my code:

```
    var idleTime = 0;
    var activeTime = 0;
    var warningFlag = 0;
    var loginTime = new Date();
    var logoutTime = loginTime;
    setInterval(function checkIdle() {
        idleTime += 1;
        activeTime += 1;
          if(idleTime > 10) {
            alert("You've been inactive for 10 \n minutes, are you still there ?\nYou logged in at " + loginTime);
            warningFlag=1;
        }
        if((idleTime > 15) && (warningFlag==1)) {
            alert("You've been logged out due to inactivity for 15 \n minutes? \nYou logged out at " + logoutTime);
            window.close();
        }
        window.onload = resetTimer;
        document.onmousemove = resetTimer;
        document.onkeypress = resetTimer;
    },1000);

    function resetTimer() {
         idleTime = 0;
    }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the "little problem" with your code? Where does it fail? What errors is it giving you?

Comment: One problem you must be having is the alert() function blocking the rest of you script ^^ (alert suspends all code until user accepts the alert)

Comment: Don't use `alert()`, because it's a modal dialog and will halt all your JavaScript until the user clicks it ... which is exactly what you don't want :)

Comment: Furthermore, just closing a window without user interaction is a restricted functionality and will only work in certain cases. I believe it only works on windows that where opened by javascipt. In firefox there is a setting that allows you to do this (dom.allow_scripts_to_close_windows), but that only works if you have access to the clients browser settings (intranet?)

Comment: so what shall i do ? yes Alert is blocking my script.. but i want the notification(alert) to bring user from any tab to the one initiated the alert....

Comment: Instead a suggestion, why not just redirect people to a login page(going through a logout page first)?
Some more points of improvement:
- You got seconds instead of minutes; 
- Alert is blocking, as said above; 
- JavaScript timing is highly inaccurate. Try syncing it with the server every few minutes.

Comment: @ReneGeuze sure i can do that thing.. it comes on later.. my focus at the moment is to perform the function: on a particualr site diaplay inactivity notificayin (JS Alert or any other thing) and after 5 more minutes of inactivity .. logout and take user to login page.

Comment: I absolutely hate my bank for "bringing me from any tab to the one that initiated the alert."  It's very jarring to be in the middle of typing (like here for example) and have the browser jump to another page all of a sudden.

Comment: @Pointy yep but its my requirement even though it is annoying

Comment: Only an alert will let you bring the tab back into view (and I pray fervently that browsers will someday allow me to decline that "feature"), but if the user doesn't respond the page will stay visible and your timer can't continue. (It *might* be possible to find a solution that uses a long polling trick ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of alert window use a div for that visibility hidden/visible is toggled. That div should contain another container, div or span, for displaying the countdown time.

Comment: how will this div behave like an alert ?

Comment: This is probably a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal windows, they behave like alerts by displaying a div and blacking out the rest of the page.

You can see some good examples here:

http://www.scriptiny.com/2011/03/javascript-modal-windows/

Hope this helps.